# Switch Perspective in e4 (Kepler)

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse 3.7 code, I have 2 editors associated with 2 different perspective. When editor activated, switch perspective through editor part handler after some check. It works fine in 3.7.But when the same code has been migrated to e4 (Kepler SR2), the perspective switch goes on in cyclic loop. How I can resolve this?

Comment: I take it you mean the 3.x compatibility mode of Kepler (pure e4 does not have editors!). Show us your code.

Comment: using the following code for perspective switch editorSite.getWorkbenchWindow().getWorkbench().showPerspective(perspectiveId, editorSite.getWorkbenchWindow());

Comment: Try running the switch code using `Display.asyncExec`

Comment: Thanks..Though it works, but UI fluctuates a lot before respective perspective stands still.